# 500 (Internal Server Error) of external php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am currently using WP Web Scraper version 3.2. Once I insert the shortcode or template tag (php code) directly into my page, the plugin works perfectly fine and the values appear. I decided to place the template tag in an external php file and use Ajax to call the code after a specific amount of time, and once I do so nothing appears and my console shows 500 (Internal Server Error). I get a message which says "Failed to load resource". My php file (test.php) contains this (assuming that URL is the actual link to the website):

```
<?php
echo wpws_get_content('URL', 'body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(8)' );
```

On my page, I use Javascript to load this file and it looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
setInterval(function () {
    $('#demo').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#demo').load('http://localhost:8888/test-site/wp-content/my-php-files/test.php', function() {
            $('#demo').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 6000);
});
</script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

I tested the PHP file with other codes to check if they work and they work perfectly fine. One example of php I inserted in that file was:

```
<?php
echo(rand(10,100));
```

In this last example, using my script, a random number is loaded from the external file every 6 seconds without having to refresh the page and I get no errors. I deduced from this the template tag provided by the plugin is causing the problem. How can I load this template tag into my script? Any suggestions?

King regards!!

Comment: Do you have access to your server logs?

Comment: what about file permissions?

Comment: I am running my website on a localserver as you know, and I have permission to create, read, write, etc because it is not the first file I have created. I tested with the same file the other code and it worked, so it has access to the file. Where can I check just in case?

Comment: @AvaBarbilla if you are on a local machine, just check the file properties (if on Windows, fetch file properties from the context menu)and see permissions, if you want to check files permissions on a server, you will need a way to connect to server files such as ssh access or GUI based stuff such as file zilla or cpanel

Comment: Enable php error logs to discover what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for me was loading the WordPress environment into the php file by inserting this line of code at the top:

```
require('../../wp-blog-header.php');
```